# phpmyadmin access denied #1045

Tags: phpmyadmin, access-denied

I have just installed wamp server 2.2. When I installed it on my laptop 6 days ago it worked fine right away without any problems. I have decided to put it on my home desktop PC as well. However when I try to go on to my localhost/phpmyadmin I get:

Error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I have not changed any passwords or anything. All I have done is installed the wamp server. I have goggled a lot and some suggested to change: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = 'true';` (that the missing quotes were the problem). That didn't help. There is no password set up so I don't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cud you access mysql console without password? first try it from tray menu icon of wamp.

`MySQL >> MySQL console.`

Comment: When I try accessing mysql via mysql console : MySQL >> MySQL console, it immediately asks me for password

Comment: ok, just press **enter** key, if there is no password set, it'll show **welcome message**. let me know wat is the result. :)

Comment: I press enter and it shows some message and closes the window right away. It's too fast so I can't read it:/

Comment: I did a printscreen. It says: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:NO)

Comment: There is another way to check that you have a password set.

go to: **http://localhost/sqlbuddy/login.php**.

If you are not able to login there, you have a password set.

Comment: If I don't put anything in the password field then I get the message: There was a problem logging you in.

Comment: try reinstalling wamp, it'll remove any password if you have accidently set for mysql.

Comment: I uninstalled wamp. ran ccleaner to clean registry, installed wamp. Did these steps only and nothing else and the same thing is happening.

Comment: **http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,87983** Try this, read last comment on that page.

Comment: Have done exactly what is in the last comment there. Still my wamp icon is orange and getting the same error. I don't understand it:/

Comment: If it is in orange, one of your service is missing. May be Apache or MySQl. Try to install them from tray icon menu. 

MySQL >> Service >> Install service.

Apache >> Service >> Install service.

see there is IIS or Skype running on your system

Comment: MySQL >> Service >> Install service didn't do anything. I have disabled IIS and skype is not running currently.

Comment: I found an old version of mysql (which i installed over a year ago). Uninstalled it and not it finally works. Thank you for all your help though. Was my bad

Answer (score 1):

If you can Login by MYSQL Console then Change Root Password

SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');

and set

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

set in:
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Do Not change in :
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Comment: When I try logging in to mysql via console, it says: Enter Password: 
I have not set a password before, I have only just installed it.
the /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php is set just as you described it.

Answer (score 0):

I messed with this problem for the better part of an entire day doing everything suggested on this site as well as suggested solutions form other sites, including completely reinstalling WAMP several times.  I had entered a password the day before from the mysql console but after trying to get Dreamweaver to connect to the database something got messed up and I could no longer open the phpMyAdmin window. In the end a super simple solution solved the problem - when the error message screen appeared, yet again, while trying to open phpMyAdmin the was a tiny blue "?" button (help button) on the top which in frustration I clicked and it asked me for a password, which I supplied - the one I had created the day before, and suddenly up comes the phpMyAdmin window.  It has been fine ever since.  If everything else fails try the help button.  For whatever reason it worked for me.  Go figure.....

Comment: I am facing the same issue..
I have set a password for MySql but when i am running WAMP server i.e.
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
I am facing the below issue..
"#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) "..
How can i resolve this..